# How can I set the line width using code (not QML) in Qt3D?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am displaying lines in 3D using Qt3D and QPhongMaterial. I can't set the line width, although I am using QLineWidth here is the code:

```
...
Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial* pCol = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(pRootEntity);
Qt3DRender::QEffect* effect = pCol->effect();
for (Qt3DRender::QTechnique* t : effect->techniques()) {
    for (Qt3DRender::QRenderPass* rp : t->renderPasses()) {
        Qt3DRender::QLineWidth* lineWidth = new Qt3DRender::QLineWidth(rp);
        lineWidth->setValue(2.0);
        lineWidth->setSmooth(true);
        rp->addRenderState(lineWidth);
    }
}
pCol->setDiffuse(QColor(r, g, b));
pCol->setSpecular(QColor(r, g, b));
pCol->setAmbient(QColor(r, g, b));
...
```

No matter what parameter in lineWidth->setValue() function I set, the width stays the same. Does someone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: I use Qt 6.2.3.

Comment: Have you tried using a `QRenderStateSet` in your framegraph and add the line width render state there? Maybe you don't want that as the final solution but it would be a starting point if that works. [This is an example in QML](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/tests/manual/pointlinesize/Scene.qml) that you could translate to C++.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I don't work with QML, so I don't know how to use it in code. Do you have some example or link that could help me.